# Unity sound control

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, audio

Is there any possibility to turn off the sound of some scenes in unity?
Like I have a menu option containing a toggle for mute sound, then a couple of scenes without any sound after that some scenes have sound.
so how can I mute or unmute the sound of that scenes which plays sound with toggle present in my menu scene?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach different `AudioSources` for Menu track and game track.
And when you are in game scene, you can use `audio_source.Stop()` to stop that audio source or `audio_source.mute=true` to mute that audio source.[unity answers](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1229868/how-to-turn-off-audio-when-at-game-scene.html)